# DiscordJS v14 Buttons not working, DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm getting this error every time I click the button. I am using v14, and I followed how the v14 buttons should be made and work, but I don't know why this error is showing and my buttons don't work.

Err:

```js
DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required
    at SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/runner/skyanime-utilities/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:748:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/runner/skyanime-utilities/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:560:14)
    at async REST.request (/home/runner/skyanime-utilities/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1000:22)
    at async GuildChannelManager.create (/home/runner/skyanime-utilities/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildChannelManager.js:145:18)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:393:10) {
  rawError: {
    code: 50035,
    errors: {
      name: {
        _errors: [
          {
            code: 'BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED',
            message: 'This field is required'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    message: 'Invalid Form Body'
  },
  code: 50035,
  status: 400,
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/1000655001888235540/channels',
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: {
      name: undefined,
      topic: undefined,
      type: undefined,
      nsfw: undefined,
      bitrate: undefined,
      user_limit: undefined,
      parent_id: undefined,
      position: undefined,
      permission_overwrites: undefined,
      rate_limit_per_user: undefined,
      rtc_region: undefined,
      video_quality_mode: undefined
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my button handler: https://sourceb.in/FepPx2RpCK

And my interaction handler: https://sourceb.in/h5zEL0I3oF

And my command definition: https://sourceb.in/RstCfscZpY

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens during channel creation. The first argument (channel name) has been moved to the `name` property.

Change

```js
await guild.channels.create(`${customId + "-" + ID}`, {
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    parent: parent_ID,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: member.id,
            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages, PermissionsBitField.Flags.ReadMessageHistory],
        },
        {
            id: everyone_ID,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages, PermissionsBitField.Flags.ReadMessageHistory],
        },
    ],
})
```

To

```js
await guild.channels.create({
    name: `${customId + "-" + ID}`,
    type: ChannelType.GuildText,
    parent: parent_ID,
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            id: member.id,
            allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages, PermissionsBitField.Flags.ReadMessageHistory],
        },
        {
            id: everyone_ID,
            deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel, PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages, PermissionsBitField.Flags.ReadMessageHistory],
        },
    ],
})
```

Comment: im getting **Type '"VIEW_CHANNEL"[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<PermissionsBitField>': any, has, missing, serialize, and 7 more.**

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to send your `command.data` as JSON.

```
const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    //convert the data to JSON as below
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}
```

{
body: **commands**
}

Comment: Are you sure you wanted to post this here as an answer to this question? Because it has nothing to do with it. If you check the error message you can see that it's a POST request to `https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/1000655001888235540/channels`, so OP wants to create a channel. There is no error with `command.data`. See the top answer for solution.