# How do I fix this error: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am learning how to code Discord bots, and I followed a YouTube video to create a reaction role bot, but I keep getting the error:

DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

I appreciate any help I can get! I copy and pasted the relevant code below.

This is the reactions.js file which is what I think is causing the error:

```
const {SlashCommandBuilder, EmbedBuilder, PermissionsBitField} = require('discord.js');
const reaction = require('../../models/Reaction');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('reactionrole')
        .setDescription('creates a message with reaction roles')
        .addSubcommand(
            command => command.setName('add').setDescription('add a reaction role to a message').addStringOption(
                option => option.setName('message-id').setDescription('the message to react to').setRequired(true)
                )
            .addStringOption(option => option.setName('emoji').setDescription('the emoji to react with').setRequired(true)).addRoleOption(
                option => option.setName('role').setDescription('the role you want to give').setRequired(true)
                )
        )
        .addSubcommand(
            command => command.setName('remove').setDescription('remove a reaction role from a message').addStringOption(
                option => option.setName('message-id').setDescription('the message to react to').setRequired(true)
                )
            .addStringOption(option => option.setName('emoji').setDescription('the emoji to react with').setRequired(true))
        ),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const {options, guild, channel} = interaction;
        const sub = options.getSubCommand();
        const emoji = options.getString('emoji');

        let e;
        const message = await channel.messages.fetch(options.getString('message-id')).catch(err => {
            e = err;
        });

        if(!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)) {
            return await interaction.reply({content: `you don't have perms to use this system`, ephemeral: true});
        }

        if(e) {
            return await interaction.reply({content: `be sure to get a message from ${channel}!`, ephemeral: true});
        }

        const data = await reaction.findOne({Guild: guild.id, Message: message.id, Emoji: emoji});

        switch(sub) {
            case 'add':

            if(data) {
                return await interaction.reply({content: `it looks like you already have this reaction setup using ${emoji} on this message`, ephemeral: true});
            } else {
                const role = options.getRole('role');
                await reaction.create({
                    // name: a,
                    Guild: guild.id,
                    Message: messsage.id,
                    Emoji: emoji,
                    Role: role.id,
                });

                const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                    .setColor("Blurple")
                    .setDescription(`i have added a reaction role to ${message.url} with ${emoji} and the role ${role}`)

                await message.react(emoji).catch(err => {});

                await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true});
            }
            break;
            case 'remove':
                
                if(!data) {
                    return await interaction.reply({content: `it doesn't look like that reaction role exists`, ephemeral: true});
                } else {
                    await reaction.deleteMany({
                        Guild: guild.id,
                        Message: message.id,
                        Emoji: emoji
                    });

                    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
                        .setColor("Blurple")
                        .setDescription(`i have removed the reaction role from ${message.url} with ${emoji}`)

                        await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed], ephemeral: true});
                }
        }
    }, 
};
```

This is the Reaction.js file:

```
const{model, Schema} = require('mongoose');

let reaction = new Schema({
    Guild: String,
    Message: String,
    Emoji: String,
    Role: String,
});

module.exports = model('Reaction', reaction);
```

This is the index.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const{Client, IntentsBitField, Events} = require('discord.js');
const eventHandler = require('./handlers/eventHandler');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildPresences,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
    ],
});

(async () => {
    try {
        mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log("connected to DB");
        eventHandler(client);

        client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    }
})();

const reactions = require('./models/Reaction');
client.on(Events.MessageReactionAdd, async (reaction, user) => {
    if(!reaction.message.guildId) return;
    if(user.bot) return;

    let cID = `<:${reaction.emoji.name}:${reaction.emoji.id}>`;
    if(!reaction.emoji.id) cID = reaction.emoji.name;

    const data = await reactions.findOne({Guild: reaction.message.guildId, Message: reaction.message.id, Emoji: cID});
    if(!data) return;

    const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(reaction.message.guildId);
    const member = await guild.members.cache.get(user.Id);

    try {
        await member.roles.add(data.Role);
    } catch(e) {
        return;
    }
});

client.on(Events.MessageReactionRemove, async (reaction, user) => {
    if(!reaction.message.guildId) return;
    if(user.bot) return;

    let cID = `<:${reaction.emoji.name}:${reaction.emoji.id}>`;
    if(!reaction.emoji.id) cID = reaction.emoji.name;

    const data = await reactions.findOne({Guild: reaction.message.guildId, Message: reaction.message.id, Emoji: cID});
    if(!data) return;

    const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(reaction.message.guildId);
    const member = await guild.members.cache.get(user.Id);

    try {
        await member.roles.remove(data.Role);
    } catch(e) {
        return;
    }
});
```

I tried searching up the error and using ChatGPT to try and find what's causing the error but nothing worked. I also tried using VSCode's debugging tool, but I am somewhat of a beginner to coding and this is my first time coding in Javascript, so I got very confused...

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232941/discordjs-v14-buttons-not-working-discordapierror50035-invalid-form-body-nam